# Oracle flashback data archive get last x records

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, flashback

We're using Oracle FDA for auditing, and I am trying to retrieve the last x records that a user had so I can compare them and see what change with each transaction. I've been googling around for quite some time now, and I can't quite figure out how to do that with an FDA query. I know how to retrieve a particular row as of a particular date and time, like:

```
select * from user
AS OF TIMESTAMP
TO_TIMESTAMP ('12302017:17:52:00','MMDDYYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
where guid = hextoraw('0A96318C1E0E45ADB5EAE1C94EA8F7B8');
```

But how would I be able to leverage this to get me a list of all the transaction that user has had so I can get, say, the last 10?

Comment: Flashback Data Archive is for maintaining a history of table state. This is not the same as auditing. Do your tables have metadata columns which hold the username (e.g. `created_by`, `updated_by`)? Because that's the only way FDA could help you. What you need is Fine-Grained Auditing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/week10-10gdba-097438.html)

Comment: Yeah, all tables have a created_by, updated_by, created_dt and updated_dt.